# Hibernate Criterion in OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to figure out how to use hibernate criterion to get a specific set of child elements when I retrieve the parent. I have created the following example entities:

**Parent Class**

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private long parentId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<Child> children
}
```

**Child Class**

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CHILD_ID")
    private long childId

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="GENDER_ID")
    private Gender gender;
}
```

**Gender Class**

```
@Entity
public class Gender {
    @Id
    @Column(name="GENDER_ID")
    private long genderId;

    @Column(name="GENDER_IND")
    private String genderInd;
}
```

**Hibernate Criteria**

```
getSession()
    .createCriteria(Parent.class)
    .createAlias("children", "c")
    .createAlias("c.gender", "g")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("g.genderInd", "M"))
    .list()
```

This criteria gives me a list of Parents that have a male ("M") child, and it returns all of the children for each of those parents. How can I get a list of Parents that have a male child and only have the male children in the Parent.children set?

Comment: You can't. If you want a subset of children, you may not search for a parent and ask him for his children, because when asking a parent for his children, the parent returns his children, all of them. Instead, to find a subset of children you need to search for children.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I was afraid that was the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched days for the solution, i had the same problems, i have an object with a collection of traductions, and i wanted to query an object with the only current language.

I found this solution : 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

working for me, here a solution for you :

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private long parentId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    @Filter(name="gender", condition="gender.genderInd=:gender")
    private Set<Child> children
}

@Entity
@FilterDef(name="genderFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="gender", type="string" ) )
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CHILD_ID")
    private long childId

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="GENDER_ID")
    private Gender gender;
}
```

And before you do your query :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.enableFilter("genderFilter").setParameter("gender", "M");
```

Comment: This looks like it would have worked, but I have already worked around the issue. I did not know anything about filters until just now, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Criteria cr = getSession()
            .createCriteria(Parent.class)
            .createAlias("children", "c")
            .createAlias("c.gender", "g");

Criterion Malechild = Restrictions.eq("g.genderInd", "M");

Criterion NFemaleChild = Restrictions.ne("g.genderInd", "F");

LogicalExpression andExp = Restrictions.and(Malechild, NFemaleChild);

cr.add(andExp);

List results = cr.list();
```

Comment: It is nice to provide some explanation for the code you submitted as an answer.

Comment: @ George Netu:  In above example first i separately filtered out the parents having Male children then filtered out the parents doesnt have the female children. after then i joined both restrication with and logical expression which exactly gives the result parents having only male childern.

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I wanted. I do want the results of Parents with male children, but I also want the Parent entity to only contain their male children.